# Creating Chart in Excel using python

Tags: python, excel, pandas, visualization

I am doing some analysis using basic sorting and cumulative functions. I need to create a scatter plot in the excel using the data that I have created in sheet2.

I am using the Worksheet , add_chart , add_series , insert_chart functions. But unable to create the chart in the same sheet.

Code as below :

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
"""
Created on Tue Nov 07 15:25:03 2017
@author: Harsh 
"""
import numpy as np
import pandas as pd
import xlsxwriter
from pandas import ExcelWriter
from pandas import ExcelFile

#Define variables for storing file names and sheet names

input_file_path="C:\Users\paha7003\Documents\Adhoc Work\Training\python_work\OUT_Base_Sannap_1010.xls";

sheet_name = "Sheet1"

output_file_path="C:\Users\paha7003\Documents\Adhoc Work\Training\python_work\Pareto_Sannap_1010.xlsx";

#Read data from file
full_data = pd.read_excel(input_file_path, sheet_name)

#Pareto will be run on category, hence change the variable name
only_category  = full_data.loc[full_data['PrdLevel_Name'] == 'CATEGORY_NAME']
#sort based on VAL
catg_sorted =  only_category.sort('VAL', ascending = [0])

#Cummilative sum , percenetage and ctg_rank binning
catg_sorted['cum_sum'] = catg_sorted.SALVAL.cumsum()
catg_sorted['cum_perc'] = 100*catg_sorted.cum_sum/catg_sorted.SALVAL.sum()

bins = [0, 5, 10,15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
labels = [5, 10,15, 20, 25, 30, 35, 40, 45, 50, 55, 60, 65, 70, 75, 80, 85, 90, 95, 100]
catg_sorted['ctg_rank'] = pd.cut(catg_sorted['cum_perc'], bins=bins, labels=labels)
#Merge the CTG ranks calculated on the cateogry to other level in the out file

final = pd.merge(full_data , catg_sorted, how = 'inner' , on='STORECODE' )
pivot =  pd.pivot_table(final, values=['WDVAL_x' , 'PROJN_x'], index=['ctg_rank'], aggfunc=np.sum)

pivot['cum_sum_wdval'] = pivot.WDVAL_x.cumsum()
pivot['cum_sum_projn'] = pivot.PROJN_x.cumsum()
pivot['cum_perc_wdval'] = 100*pivot.cum_sum_wdval/pivot.WDVAL_x.sum()
pivot['cum_perc_projn'] = 100*pivot.cum_sum_projn/pivot.PROJN_x.sum()

#Writing output data to new file
writer = pd.ExcelWriter(output_file_path , engine='xlsxwriter')
full_data.to_excel(writer,'Sheet1')
pivot.to_excel(writer, 'Sheet2')
writer.save()

workbook = writer.book
worksheet = writer.sheets['Sheet2']
chart5 = workbook.add_chart({'type': 'scatter','subtype': 'smooth'})

# Configure the first series.
chart5.add_series({
    'name':       ['Sheet2', 2, 0],
    'categories': ['Sheet2', 2, 0, 4, 0],
    'values':     ['Sheet2', 2, 6, 4, 6],
})

# Add a chart title and some axis labels.
chart5.set_title ({'name': 'Pareto Graph'})
chart5.set_x_axis({'name': '#Stores'})
chart5.set_y_axis({'name': 'Wdval'})


# Set an Excel chart style.
chart5.set_style(15)
worksheet.insert_chart('M7', chart5)
workbook.close()
writer.save()
```